# unexpected preg match behavior with \s and?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

It's quite simple, I don't understand why the following does match:

```
preg_match('/\<td valign="top" class="bericht"\>(.*\s)*<\/td>/',$html,$matches3);
```

And this one does not:

```
preg_match('/\<td valign="top" class="bericht"\>(.*(\s)?)*<\/td>/',$html,$matches3);
```

I thought ? meant zero or one. So I don't see how that can make something not match.

When testing with RegexPal (http://regexpal.com/) everything works as expected. So the second one does match.

Comment: You might need to use a PHP regex tester instead of a JavaScript regex tester.

Comment: @Blazemonger using http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php gives me the following answer: int(0). I guess that means no match.

Comment: You are far better off using DOMDocument/XPath for this kind of manipulation than regex. Just saying.

Comment: @holodoc I have realised that, and am planning to. But as this code is used at this moment, i have to get this working as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these should match. But the second one can run into [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) because

- `.` also matches `\s` (except for, and here's the kicker, newlines)
- it uses nested infinite quantifiers (in essence, it's `(.*)*` since the `\s` is optional)

Therefore, given sufficiently large input with enough newlines, PHP will stop matching after a certain threshold of backtracks has been exceeded (you can configure this somewhere, but I forget where) whereas the online regex tester may go ahead and exhaust all the possible permutations.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Tim Pietzcker says . . .

How are you determining that the second one doesn't match? Note that, whereas the first pattern will set `$matches3[1]` to the contents of the table-cell, the second pattern will always set `$matches3[1]` to the empty string.

Suppose that `$html` looks like this:

```
<td valign="top" class="bericht">yes </td>
```

Then the `(.*\s)*` in the first pattern will match `yes`  and nothing else after that, so it will store `yes`  in `$matches3[1]`.

But the `(.*(\s)?)*` in the second pattern will match `yes`  *and then the empty string after that*, so it will store the empty string in `$matches3[1]`.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but if your goal is just to capture everything between `<td valign="top" class="bericht">` and `</td>`, regardless of what that might be, then you should write:

```
preg_match('/\<td valign="top" class="bericht"\>(.*?)<\/td>/s',$html,$matches3);
```

(where the `*?` means "zero or more times, but preferably as few as possible, and the `/s` means "allow `.` to match any character at all, even newline").